# PouchDB with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, pouchdb

I'm trying to use PouchDB with jQuery. The problem is that I'm not being able to use the 'put' method inside my app.js. It works pretty well on the document.ready function, but it doesn't work into the other functions of the code. I mean, when the page loads, it creates a new row into the database, but when I submit the form, it doesn't do anything.
(Note: 'prueba' means 'test' in spanish).

Here is my index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Prueba PouchDB</title>
    <script src="pouchdb.js"></script>

    <script src="jquery.js"></script>

    <script src="base.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="crearEntrada">
        <form method="post">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Texto" name="texto" id="texto"
                                            autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off"
                                            autocomplete="off" />
            <input type="submit" class="submit" name="action"
                                            value="Guardar entrada" />
        </form>
    </div>

    <div id="mostrarRegistros">
        <button onclick="showTodos()">Mostrar Registros</button>
        <ul>
            <li id="entryTemplate" class="entry" style="display:none ;text-align: center">
                <span class="registro">Registro</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</body>
```

Here is my app.js:

```
var db = new PouchDB('prueba');
var remoteCouch = false;
var ENTER_KEY = 13;
var newTodoDom = document.getElementById('new-todo');
var syncDom = document.getElementById('sync-wrapper');
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#crearEntrada form').submit(addTodo);
    'use strict';

    db.put({
        _id:"406",
        title:"Example",
        completed:false
    });

    // EDITING STARTS HERE (you dont need to edit anything above this line)


    showTodos();

    if (remoteCouch) {
        sync();
    }
});

function addTodo() {

    var db = new PouchDB('prueba');
    db.put({
        _id:"408",
title:"Another example",
completed:false
    });

    var texto= $('#texto').val();
    alert(texto);
    var todo = {
        _id: new Date().toISOString(),
title: texto,
completed: false
    };
    alert(JSON.stringify(todo));
    alert("Base de datos" + db);
    alert(JSON.stringify(db.put(todo)));

    db.put(todo).then(function(result){
        alert("Everything is A-OK");
        alert(result);
    }).catch(function (err) {
        alert("everything is terrible");
        alert(err);
    });
    alert("termino addTodo");
    /*
    db.put(todo, function callback(err, result) {
        if (!err) {
        alert('Successfully posted a todo!');
        }
        else{
            alert('Algo salio mal');
        }
    });
    */
}
// Show the current list of todos by reading them from the database
function showTodos() {
}

function checkboxChanged(todo, event) {
}

// User pressed the delete button for a todo, delete it
function deleteButtonPressed(todo) {
}

// The input box when editing a todo has blurred, we should save
// the new title or delete the todo if the title is empty
function todoBlurred(todo, event) {
}

// Initialise a sync with the remote server
function sync() {
}

// EDITING STARTS HERE (you dont need to edit anything below this line)

// There was some form or error syncing
function syncError() {
    syncDom.setAttribute('data-sync-state', 'error');
}

// User has double clicked a todo, display an input so they can edit the title
function todoDblClicked(todo) {
    var div = document.getElementById('li_' + todo._id);
    var inputEditTodo = document.getElementById('input_' + todo._id);
    div.className = 'editing';
    inputEditTodo.focus();
}

// If they press enter while editing an entry, blur it to trigger save
// (or delete)
function todoKeyPressed(todo, event) {
    if (event.keyCode === ENTER_KEY) {
        var inputEditTodo = document.getElementById('input_' + todo._id);
        inputEditTodo.blur();
    }
}

// Given an object representing a todo, this will create a list item
// to display it.
function createTodoListItem(todo) {
    var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
    checkbox.className = 'toggle';
    checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
    checkbox.addEventListener('change', checkboxChanged.bind(this, todo));

    var label = document.createElement('label');
    label.appendChild( document.createTextNode(todo.title));
    label.addEventListener('dblclick', todoDblClicked.bind(this, todo));

    var deleteLink = document.createElement('button');
    deleteLink.className = 'destroy';
    deleteLink.addEventListener( 'click', deleteButtonPressed.bind(this, todo));

    var divDisplay = document.createElement('div');
    divDisplay.className = 'view';
    divDisplay.appendChild(checkbox);
    divDisplay.appendChild(label);
    divDisplay.appendChild(deleteLink);

    var inputEditTodo = document.createElement('input');
    inputEditTodo.id = 'input_' + todo._id;
    inputEditTodo.className = 'edit';
    inputEditTodo.value = todo.title;
    inputEditTodo.addEventListener('keypress', todoKeyPressed.bind(this, todo));
    inputEditTodo.addEventListener('blur', todoBlurred.bind(this, todo));

    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.id = 'li_' + todo._id;
    li.appendChild(divDisplay);
    li.appendChild(inputEditTodo);

    if (todo.completed) {
        li.className += 'complete';
        checkbox.checked = true;
    }

    return li;
}

function redrawTodosUI(todos) {
    var ul = document.getElementById('todo-list');
    ul.innerHTML = '';
    todos.forEach(function(todo) {
        ul.appendChild(createTodoListItem(todo.doc));
    });
}
```

I'm just trying to make work the addTodo function. The rest of the code it's just copy-pasted from the pouchdb-getting-started-todo. I also put a lot of alerts to debug and some code commented.
Thanks a lot!
Leandro.

Answer (score 0):

As you have defined

```
var db = new PouchDB('prueba');
```

as a global variable you do not need to redefine db here so your todo function should look like that

```
function addTodo() {
    db.put({
     _id:"408",
     title:"Another example",
     completed:false
    });
 console.log("ToDo updated");
 }
```

or if you want to get the text from an input field I renamed the function to addTodoText

```
function addTodoText() {
    var texto= $('#texto').val();
    //alert(texto);
    db.put({
        _id: new Date().toISOString(),
       title: texto,
   completed: false
   });
 console.log("ToDo updated with " + texto);
 }
```

[Please read the pouchDB documentation](https://pouchdb.com/getting-started.html) and work through the basic examples to know what you do

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I also thought that var db didn't need to be redefined into the addTodo function, as it's a global variable. I've just tried that to look if it worked. I've tried the code you gave me but it still doesn't work. I've read the PouchDB documentation but it didn't help me too much. In the code shown at the video tutorial everything works fine, but when I try to do something a little bit different, I'm getting this problem. Thank you